# Solutions of a PDE in two dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I should solve the following PDE:
$$\dfrac{\partial u(x,y,t)}{\partial t}=a\nabla^2u(x,y,t)+b\nabla u(x,y,t)+g(x,y,t)-c u(x,y,t)$$ where $(a,b,c)$ are constants, $$u(x,y,0)=u_0$$ $$u(x,y,t)=0$$ for $0\le x\le \rho_0$, $y=\sqrt{\rho_0^2-x^2}$, $$u(x,y,t)=0$$ for $0\le x\le\rho_1$, $y=\sqrt{\rho_1^2-x^2}$.  Are there suggestions or hints? Thanks.

Comment: i think you have a typo in the equation on the 2nd term on the l.h.s. Also i would change to polar co-ordinates.

Comment: @Chinny84: What is th typo please?

Comment: @Chinny84: Ohh. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Should $b\nabla (x,y,t)$ be  $b\nabla u(x,y,t)$ ?

Comment: So. It's a diffusion equation with drift term ($b$), with decay ($c$), in a cylindrical domain (as I guess; you botched the description of the domain). What do you know about such things?